# Jquery hide show not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, hide, show

I'm having trouble solving a problem that causes my script to fail.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/N9cbk/7/) is the code I used.
Although it works flawlessly in JsFiddle, when I implement it in my site it doesn't work at all.

```
    <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $("#overlay").hide();
    $("#work").click(function(e){
        $("#overlay").toggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(document).click(function(){
        $("#overlay").hide();
    });
    $("#overlay").click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="work"></div>
    <div id="overlay"><iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/uQFGkGk4PSc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
    </body>
```

[Link to site](http://holymothership.be/)

Thanks!

Comment: Is any of the content being loaded in with AJAX?

Comment: are you sure you link to jquery.js??

Comment: Check that you include jQuery library.

Comment: linked to <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to wrap your code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#overlay").hide();
    $("#work").click(function(e){
        $("#overlay").toggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(document).click(function(){
        $("#overlay").hide();
    });
    $("#overlay").click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

});
```

On default, Fiddle runs the code on `onLoad` and you are placing it in the `<head>`. You can set the option on the left top corner. I changed it to `in <head>` and it's not working there either: http://jsfiddle.net/N9cbk/8/

Read more about `$( document ).ready()` here: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: thecodeparadox's version above is the short-hand version of this, they are both correct and will both work.

Comment: Exactly. I used the longer version because of this: _If you are writing code that people who aren't experienced with jQuery may see, it's best to use the long form._ It's from the jQuery documentation I linked to.

Comment: I know, I wrote my comment for the OP benefit :)

Comment: I know, I did't think you were criticizing my answer. :)